# Not Connecting with private LTE network

Tags: adb, 4g

I have android camera vehicle mounted device. When install operator public network LTE sim, device is successfully connected to network but when install company private LTE network sim device is not connecting.

When we try troubleshoot via adb observed no any IP assign to device with private LTE

What are the commands available to network troubleshooting via adb

Answer (score 0):

Check the supported [LTE bands (transmission frequencies)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_frequency_bands) of the device.

Your company will most likely only operate their LTE private network in one special band which has to be supported by the device. If the device does not support the necessary band/frequency then you can't use the device in the company LTE network.

Comment: Checked the band, device is supporting company LTE band. Problem is IP assigned to device from Private LTE core network side but from the device end no any IPs showing that's why need to troubleshoot from device OS level